# OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider/ AuthenticationTokenProvider ticket unique to server?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

We have a .Net Web API (v2) serving an SPA that I aim to secure using OAuth 2.

In my OWIN Startup.Configuration(), I set my Provider in IAppBuilder.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer to an override of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.  I have this successfully providing refresh tokens.

I want to be sure that these tokens cannot be spoofed by someone implementing a similar provider. No searching I have done has given me any kind of answer.

Does OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider ensure that the refresh tokens received are those issued by itself, and not any similar code on a hacker's machine?

My own experiment seems to confirm that it does - I tried the same code running on two different machines and took the unexpired refresh token (with a long expiry of 24 hours) from the other machine, and got a 401 as I'd hope.  But just in case I've wrongly convinced myself, I'd like some reassurance and/ or advice from someone who knows more about OAuth in the .Net Web API than I.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure I eventually found a definitive answer in the doc for OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider but now can't find it.

However, [Dominick Baier](http://leastprivilege.com/), an expert in this field, says:

> Access tokens are protected using the machine key. Protection of refresh tokens is up to you. You need to manually set the machineKey element in web.config (otherwise the key gets auto generated and might change over time).

His comment comes from a reply to a [post on implementing OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/embedding-a-simple-usernamepassword-authorization-server-in-web-api-v2/).